# How can I find the co-ordinate of where a line intersects a circle?

Tags: linear-algebra, circles

I was looking to know if there was an equation that would allow me to calculate the co-ordinates of a point on the circumference of a circle where a line intersects it and the center. My diagram should display this better:

[image]

So how would I know the point of $B$ if I know the co-ordinates of $A$ and $C$ and also know the equation of the line? I also know the radius of the circle.

Comment: The circle cuts the line segment in half? The way you're using "bisect" it sounds as though the circle is somehow being cut in half.

Comment: Do you actually want to say "intersect" instead of "bisect"? The two words mean very different things.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I used the wrong word. Sorry for the confusion, I have changed it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: The coordinates of the point B which is the mid point of $A(x_A, y_A)$ & $C(x_C, y_C)$ are calculated as follows 
$$B\equiv\left(\frac{x_A+x_C}{2}, \frac{y_A+y_C}{2}\right)$$
Points $A$, $B$ & $C$ will lie on the line & will satisfy its equation.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't seam to have worked. Unless I'm mistaken, the co-ordinates for B would be `((Xa + Xc) / 2, (Ya + Yc) / 2)`. I have plotted my results on a graph ([here](http://i.gyazo.com/a7e1844bee84449d32211aeab7d4066e.png)) and it isn't a circle which I assume it should be because I am plotting `b`.

Comment: @crossboy007 For a fixed circle and points $A,C$, you should only be able to plot a single point $B$; I'm not sure how you came up with that graph. I also strongly suspect that this answer doesn't apply. I think your use of the word "bisect" caused answerers to misinterpret the situation. Is the length of segment $AB$ guaranteed to be equal to that of $BC$? If not, this answer probably doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

If instead of bisection, you know the circle radius $r$ and the distance *AC* is $\ell$ then

$$ B \equiv \left(x_A + \frac{r}{\ell} (x_C-x_A), y_A + \frac{r}{\ell} (y_C-y_A) \right) $$

To get the bisection, use simply $r=\frac{\ell}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

simple analytic geometrical way:

$(x-A_x)^2 + (y-A_y)^2 = r^2$

$y = kx$

the desired point (x,y) satisfies both equations. Solve for x,y and you'll get two points (the line intersects at both ends), choose the upper one.

Comment: I'm not too sure how that will give me Xb and Yb?

Comment: x and y are Xb and Yb

Comment: But I have two unknowns so how would I go about working it out?

Comment: you have two equations, solve x or y from y=kx and substitute

Comment: Ok, sorry, I completely missed `y=kx`. I hope this isn't too much of a silly question but what does `k` stand for?

Comment: k is the slope of your line

Comment: Still I have the problem where in the second equation there are two unknowns aren't there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26443/discussion-between-user256916-and-crossboy007).